# Adding variable product attributes when adding a new product variation programmatically in WooCommerce is not working as expected

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have developed a WordPress plugin that connects WooCommerce to a 3rd party Enterprise Resource Planning (ERP) system, syncing Products, Inventory, and Prices from the ERP and sending customer and order information to the ERP.

I am having issues updating Variable Products in WooCommerce.  See this ticket on the WooCommerce GitHub that I opened:
https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/36791

> While processing (saving and/or updating) products from an external
> source, Variable and Variation products are created. During this
> process, Variation products attributes are used to update the Variable
> products attributes. Upon completion of the update, all Variable and
> Variation products are present, but the Variable product only has one
> value per attribute. Variation products have values only for values in
> the Variable products attributes. (This is expected) Manually adding
> the missing value(s) to the Variable product refreshes the Variation
> products to include the correct values with no additional user
> interaction needed. This confirms that the Variation product
> attributes are saved correctly.

This issue keeps coming back up in my system, and I can not seem to be able to program myself out of this hole.

I would very much appreciate any suggestions, or different approaches anyone here may have.

Thank you!!

This is the code attached to the above ticket that demonstrates the issue I am having:

> I have created a single file plugin that replicates this issue. The
> plugin runs on the init hook, and is commented out to start with.
> There is also a short logging function on the
> woocommerce_before_product_object_save hook (also initially commented
> out) that helps illustrate why I belive the bug occurs on the deferred
> save of a variable product.
>
> In addition to this file, you will need to create product attributes
> 'field1' with at least 'red' and 'blue' and 'field2' with at least
> 'large'

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name:     Testing Deferred Sync Bug
 * Description:     Testing plugin for WooCommerce Issue #36791
 * Author:          Mishol-IT
 * Version:         1.0.0
 */

//add_action( 'init', 'wc_36791_run_debug_plugin', 99, 0 );
//add_action( 'woocommerce_before_product_object_save', 'wc_36791_before_product_save_action', 10, 2 );

/**
 * @return void
 */
function wc_36791_run_debug_plugin() {
    $external_products = array(
        array(
            "SKU"       => "sku1",
            "IS_PARENT" => true,
            "PARENT"    => null,
            "PART_NAME" => "part1",
            "field1"    => null,
            "field2"    => null,
            "field3"    => null,
        ),
        array(
            "SKU"       => "sku2",
            "IS_PARENT" => false,
            "PARENT"    => "sku1",
            "PART_NAME" => "part2",
            "field1"    => "red",
            "field2"    => "large",
            "field3"    => null,
        ),
        array(
            "SKU"       => "sku3",
            "IS_PARENT" => false,
            "PARENT"    => "sku1",
            "PART_NAME" => "part3",
            "field1"    => "blue",
            "field2"    => "large",
            "field3"    => null,
        )
    );

    wc_36791_update_products( $external_products );
}

/**
 * @param $external_products
 *
 * @return void
 * @throws WC_Data_Exception
 */
function wc_36791_update_products( $external_products ) {
    foreach ( $external_products as $external_product ) {
        if ( !isset( $external_product ) ) {
            continue;
        }

        $sku       = $external_product["SKU"];
        $parent    = $external_product["IS_PARENT"];
        $variation = $external_product["PARENT"] && !$parent;

        if ( $variation ) {
            wc_36791_update_product_variation( $external_product );
            continue;
        }

        $existing = wc_get_product_id_by_sku( $sku );

        if ( $parent ) {
            $wc_product = new WC_Product_Variable( $existing ?? 0 );
            $wc_product->set_manage_stock( false );
        } else {
            $wc_product = new WC_Product_Simple( $existing ?? 0 );
            $wc_product->set_manage_stock( true );
        }

        $wc_product->set_sku( $sku );

        if ( !$existing ) {
            $wc_product->set_name( $external_product["PART_NAME"] );
            $wc_product->set_status( 'draft' );
            $wc_product->set_slug( "p_" . $sku );
        }

        $wc_product->save();
    }
}

/**
 * @param $external_product
 *
 * @return void
 * @throws WC_Data_Exception
 */
function wc_36791_update_product_variation( $external_product ) {
    $arrtibuteFields = array( "field1", "field2", "field3" );
    $sku             = $external_product["SKU"];
    $parent_sku      = $external_product["PARENT"];
    $parent          = new WC_Product_Variable( wc_get_product_id_by_sku( $parent_sku ) );

    $existing          = wc_get_product_id_by_sku( $sku );
    $product_Variation = new WC_Product_Variation( $existing ?? 0 );
    $product_Variation->set_name( $parent->get_name() );
    $product_Variation->set_slug( "p_" . $sku );
    $product_Variation->set_parent_id( $parent->get_id() );
    $product_Variation->set_manage_stock( true );
    $product_Variation->set_sku( $sku );

    $attributes = array();
    foreach ( $arrtibuteFields as $term ) {
        if ( isset( $external_product[$term] ) ) {
            $attributes['pa_' . strtolower( $term )] = sanitize_title( $external_product[$term] );
        }
    }

    if ( $attributes ) {
        $old_attributes = $product_Variation->get_attributes();
        $merged         = array_merge( $old_attributes, $attributes );
        $product_Variation->set_attributes( $merged );
    }

    $product_Variation->save();

    wc_36791_update_parent_attributes( $arrtibuteFields, $product_Variation, $parent );
}

/**
 * @param array                $arrtibuteFields
 * @param WC_Product_Variation $variation
 * @param WC_Product_Variable  $parent
 *
 * @return void
 */
function wc_36791_update_parent_attributes( $arrtibuteFields, WC_Product_Variation $variation, WC_Product_Variable $parent ) {
    $position   = 0;
    $attributes = array();

    foreach ( $arrtibuteFields as $specField ) {
        $variation_attributes = $variation->get_attributes();
        $slug                 = 'pa_' . strtolower( $specField );

        if ( array_key_exists( $slug, $variation_attributes ) ) {
            $term = get_term_by( 'name', $variation_attributes[$slug], $slug );

            $attribute = new WC_Product_Attribute();
            $attribute->set_id( wc_attribute_taxonomy_id_by_name( $slug ) );
            $attribute->set_name( $slug );
            $attribute->set_options( array( $term->term_id ) );
            $attribute->set_position( $position++ );
            $attribute->set_visible( true );
            $attribute->set_variation( true );

            $attributes[$slug] = $attribute;
        }
    }

    $merged = wc_36791_merge_attribute_arrays( $attributes, $parent->get_attributes() );

    $parent->set_attributes( $merged );
    $parent->save();
}

/**
 * Combines two arrays of WC_Product_Attribute objects, running array_merge() on options arrays from duplicate slugs
 *
 * @param WC_Product_Attribute[] $new_attributes
 * @param WC_Product_Attribute[] $parent_attributes
 *
 * @return WC_Product_Attribute[]
 */
function wc_36791_merge_attribute_arrays( $new_attributes, $parent_attributes ) {
    $merged = $parent_attributes;
    foreach ( $new_attributes as $new_attribute ) {
        $name = $new_attribute->get_name();
        if ( isset( $merged[$name] ) ) {
            $parent_options = $merged[$name]->get_options();
            $new_options    = $new_attribute->get_options();
            $merged_options = array_unique( array_merge( $new_options, $parent_options ) );
            $merged[$name]->set_options( $merged_options );
        } else {
            $merged[$name] = $new_attribute;
        }
    }
    return $merged;
}

/**
 * @param WC_Data          $product    The object being saved.
 * @param WC_Data_Store_WP $data_store THe data store persisting the data.
 */

function wc_36791_before_product_save_action( $product, $data_store ) {
    error_log( "Before Product Save" );
    error_log( "The Product ID: " . $product->get_id() );
    error_log( "The Product Class: " . get_class( $product ) );
    if ($product instanceof WC_Product_Variable) {
        error_log( "Stack Trace: " . json_encode( wp_debug_backtrace_summary( pretty: false ) ) );
        error_log( "The Product Data: " . print_r( $product->get_data(), true ) );
    }
}
```